# Group transactions and place it in a single cell of the grouped category

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Input Data

| Name | City |
| --- | --- |
| First | A |
| Second | B |
| First | A |
| First | B |
| Second | B |
| First | Z |
| First | B |
| Second | X |

Output Data

| Name | City_Summary |
| --- | --- |
| First | A B Z |
| Second | B X |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_agg`:

```
select name, array_agg(name) City_Summary
from table_name
group by name
```

Your output (with space as delimiter) would be the result of:

```
select name, string_agg(name, ' ') City_Summary
from table_name
group by name
```

Comment: This one worked superb, thanks @Andronicus for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation with distinct as follows:

```
Select name, string_agg(distinct city, ' ') as cities
From t
Group by name
```